# url issues with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an example at the [following url](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0862025/CodeIgniter/index.php/form), which sends the user to a basic form.

The code for the form is the following;

```
<?php  echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>
```

If I understand correctly, once the user presses "submit", it should go back to the controller named "form". But it does not work as expected.

I would want it to submit to `index.php/form`, and instead it goes to `/index.php/index.php/form`

Feel free to test out website at url above and see the issue by yourself.

Comment: Try this: `<?php echo form_open('../form'); ?>` or leave it unchanged  `<?php echo form_open(''); ?>`

Comment: What is your base_url set to in your config file?

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at your source code and noticed this:

```
<form action="http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0862025/CodeIgniter/index.php/index.php/form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Which displays two "index.php"s. This likely means you have "index.php" set in your base url AND index page configuration. You should remove the "index.php" from one of those sources, preferably from your base_url.

Answer (score 1):

Check your base_url() in config file. If it is correclty, than you can write the form like this:

```
<?php  echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('controller_name/function_name'); 
      // controller name write your name of controller 
      // and function name write your function 
?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

<?php echo form_close(); // don't forget to close correct ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this situation once and the problem was i have included index.php in my base_url in `./application/config/config.php` file please check and remove if present. You can also solve your problem by removing index.php from index_page key but it is not a good practice to include index.php in your base_url.